# How to save data in textarea on enter key using ajax like facebook comment?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, m

I have done the code like this in view page and controller done in codeigniter
While pressing enter key multiple times data saving to the table. Can anybody help to solve this problem

**View Page**

```
<form>
<div class="cmt-box">
<textarea class="form-control" name="txtArea" id="txtArea<?php echo $row->id;?>" onkeypress="onTestChange(1)" rows="1"></textarea>
</div></form>
```

script

```
function onTestChange(id) { 
  $("#txtArea"+id).keypress(function(e) {  
   if(e.which == 13) {

dataString=document.getElementById("txtArea"+id).value;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo site_url('show/insertcomment'); ?>",
  data: { comment :dataString, id:id},
  success: function(data){
 location.reload();
  }

});
 }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".class_txtarea").keypress(function(e) {  
   if(e.which == 13) {

     dataString=document.getElementById(this).value;
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo site_url('show/insertcomment'); ?>",
      data: { comment :dataString, id:id},
      success: function(data){
          location.reload();
      }

   });
 }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="cmt-box">
    <textarea class="form-control mytext" name="txtArea" id="txtArea<?php echo $row->id;?>" rows="1"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mytext').keyup(function (evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) { /* pressed enter key */
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('show/insertcomment'); ?>",
                data: { comment :dataString, id:id},
                success: function(data){
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```